# Having trouble with cells repeating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have the following method that loads cells into my table.  The cell with text "No Results" is being repeated though as I scroll.  What am I doing wrong with the dequeueing?

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *aCell = [iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if (aCell == nil) {
        aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellID] autorelease];
    }

    if (iTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        if (self.isSearching) {
            static NSString *aProgressIdentifier = @"SearchProgress";
            aCell = [iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aProgressIdentifier];
            if (!aCell) {
                aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:aProgressIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            aCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            aLabel.text = @"Searching...";
            aLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
            aLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            aLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            [aLabel sizeToFit];
            aLabel.frame = CGRectMake(floorf((self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - (aLabel.frame.size.width / 2.0f)), floorf((aCell.frame.size.height / 2.0f) - (aLabel.frame.size.height / 2.0f)), aLabel.frame.size.width, aLabel.frame.size.height);
            [aCell addSubview:aLabel];
            [aLabel release];

            UIActivityIndicatorView *aSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            [aCell addSubview:aSpinner];
            aSpinner.frame = CGRectMake(floorf((aCell.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - (aSpinner.frame.size.width / 2.0f)) - floorf(aLabel.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - 20.0f, floorf((aCell.frame.size.height / 2.0f) - (aSpinner.frame.size.height / 2.0f)), aSpinner.frame.size.width, aSpinner.frame.size.height);
            [aSpinner startAnimating];
            [aSpinner release];
        } else {
            Class anObject = [self.masterArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.section];
            if ([anObject isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]) {
                NSArray *sectionArray = [self.masterArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.section];
                if (sectionArray.count > 0) {
                    id aCellObject = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row];
                    if ([aCellObject isKindOfClass:[CMACustomer class]]) {
                        CMACustomer *aCustomerObject = aCellObject;
                        aCell.textLabel.
                        text = aCustomerObject.customerFullName;
                        aCell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;                
                    } else if ([aCellObject isKindOfClass:[CMAReservation class]]) {
                        CMAReservation *aReservationObject = aCellObject;
                        aCell.textLabel.text = aReservationObject.fullName;
                        aCell.detailTextLabel.text = aReservationObject.orderDescription;     
//                        aCell.detailTextLabel.text = aReservationObject.reservationTimeAndDate;                
                    } 
                } else {
                    aCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                    aLabel.text = @"No Results.";
                    aLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
                    aLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                    aLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                    [aLabel sizeToFit];
                    aLabel.frame = CGRectMake(floorf((self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - (aLabel.frame.size.width / 2.0f)), floorf((aCell.frame.size.height / 2.0f) - (aLabel.frame.size.height / 2.0f)), aLabel.frame.size.width, aLabel.frame.size.height);
                    [aCell addSubview:aLabel];
                    [aLabel release];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSString *aLocalizedTitle = [[self.defaultScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"localizedTitle"];
        NSString *aDefaultTitle = [[self.defaultScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"defaultTitle"];
        aCell.textLabel.text = CMALocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(aLocalizedTitle, aDefaultTitle);

        if ([[[self.currentScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"enabledByDefault"] boolValue]) {
            aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
    return aCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. If you just want text labels in your cells there is no need to add a `UILabel` to the `tableViewCell`. Just use the `textLabel` property of the cell or the `detailTextLabel` property (depending on the `tableviewcell` type you're using).
2. If you do want to add a `UILabel` you should add it to the `contentView` property of the `tableViewCell`.
3. When you are adding views to a `tableViewcell`, you really shouldn't `alloc/init` it outside of the `if(!Cell) {}` block as every time you're recycling that `tableViewcell`, another another `UILabel` is `alloc/init`'d.
4. According to the code you posted and the problem you are seeing, it looks like `sectionArray`is empty. Where is that being filled?

Comment: Sorry, I removed a lot of the code but I'm adding the labels because I'm customizing the look so they don't look like regular textLabel.  SectionArray is filled by this `NSArray *sectionArray = [self.masterArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.section];`  I just kept the code I posted to the minimum

Comment: I just removed the code and added the full code I'm using.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, there could be a number of things going wrong here. The first thing I would start with is checking that: `[self.masterArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.section]` is returning a non-empty array. If it is empty, that would explain why your `if (sectionArray.count > 0) {}` is getting tripped for each cell, giving you a "No Results" for each UILabel.

Comment: It's not changing the whole cell to "No Resluts".  The cells are loading fine, but when I scroll, the no results text will be behind a random cells.

Comment: Another thing you may want to look at is using the `accessoryView` property of the `tableviewcell` for your `UIActivityIndicatorView` instead of just adding it as a `subview` of your `UITableViewCell`. I would highly recommend reading Apple's docs on [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That should definitely make your life a bit easier.

Comment: I got it working.  I just added a different identifier for each type of cell (pretty much for each if statement) and changed  static NSString *aProgressIdentifier = @"SearchProgress";
            aCell = [iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aProgressIdentifier];
            if (!aCell) {
                aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:aProgressIdentifier] autorelease];
            } also.